# Server-side json "ajax" calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying use Places API from Google frmo a node.js server

This is the url I'm trying to access.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=parkings+in+Madrid,Spain&sensor=true&key=key

Which is the best way to process request from server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`https.get`](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) or [`https.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback).

```
const https = require("https");

https.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=parkings+in+Madrid,Spain&sensor=true&key=key", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```